# How can I check whether a shell argument is of type .csv?

Tags: shell

I'd like to look for a .csv file in arguments passed into function. I want to print each one and when I find a .csv file I want it to just say yes. I got this:

```
for I in $*
do
    echo "$I"
    if [[ "$I" = '*.csv' ]]
    then
        echo "yes"
    fi

done
```

it's not working however. What's the correct way of doing this?

Comment: It is not clear, which shell you are using. You are tagging it with _shell_, which means _POSIX shell_, but POSIX shell does not have `[[`. You would have to use zsh (or ksh, or bash) in order to use it. Please clarify this first.

Comment: Also, files don't have "types". You seem to test, whether the filename obeys a certain pattern (i.e. the last 4 characters being `.csv`), which is something different.

Answer (score 0):

Looping on files using `for I in $*` is fraught with danger.  Ex. it will fail if there is a space in the filename.  See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for safe ways of doing this.

That being said, I would use `find` to do this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.csv" -exec printf "%s\nyes\n" {} \;
```

- `-maxdepth 1`: avoids recursion and only process CSV files in the current directory.
- `printf "%s\nyes\n" {}`: prints the filename and 'yes' on the next line.  This matches your `echo` output.

Ex:

```
$ ls
a.csv  b.csv
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.csv" -exec printf "%s\nyes\n" {} \;
./a.csv
yes
./b.csv
yes
$
```